# BIServerComponent - Could not get details about the specified host

Tags: components, redhat, hostname, obiee

I have an OBIEE 11g installation in a Red Hat machine, but I'm finding problems to make it running. I can start WebLogic and its services, so I’m able to enter the WebLogic console and Enterprise Manager, but problems come when I try to start OBIEE components with opmnctl command.

Set up OBIEE Components

```
cd /home/Oracle/Middleware/instances/instance1/bin/
./opmnctl startall
```

Check the status of components

```
cd /home/Oracle/Middleware/instances/instance1/bin/
./opmnctl status

Processes in Instance: instance1
---------------------------------+--------------------+---------+---------
ias-component                    | process-type       |     pid | status  
---------------------------------+--------------------+---------+---------
coreapplication_obiccs1          | OracleBIClusterCo~ |    8221 | Alive   
coreapplication_obisch1          | OracleBIScheduler~ |     N/A | Down    
coreapplication_obijh1           | OracleBIJavaHostC~ |    8726 | Alive   
coreapplication_obips1           | OracleBIPresentat~ |    6921 | Alive   
coreapplication_obis1            | OracleBIServerCom~ |     N/A | Down
```

OracleBIServerComponent is in "Down" status and i have checked the problem in Enterprise Manager. The content of log is:

```
[2014-03-20T10:23:47.000+00:00] [OracleBIServerComponent] [NOTIFICATION:1] [] [] [ecid: 004xGPJYrnnFw00Fzzx0g00006Gb000000] [tid: fb3c8c60]  [36007] Loading repository /home/Oracle/Middleware/instances/instance1/bifoundation/OracleBIServerComponent/coreapplication_obis1/repository/Justizia_BI0011.rpd.

[2014-03-20T10:23:48.000+00:00] [OracleBIServerComponent] [NOTIFICATION:1] [] [] [ecid: 004xGPJYrnnFw00Fzzx0g00006Gb000000] [tid: 43cf5940]  [14055] Loading subject area: JUSTICIA_F1 ...

[2014-03-20T10:23:48.000+00:00] [OracleBIServerComponent] [NOTIFICATION:1] [] [] [ecid: 004xGPJYrnnFw00Fzzx0g00006Gb000000] [tid: 43cf5940]  [14056] Finished loading subject area: JUSTICIA_F1.

[2014-03-20T10:23:48.000+00:00] [OracleBIServerComponent] [NOTIFICATION:1] [] [] [ecid: 004xGPJYrnnFw00Fzzx0g00006Gb000000] [tid: fb3c8c60]  [85003] MDX Member Name Cache subsystem started successfully.

[2014-03-20T10:23:48.000+00:00] [OracleBIServerComponent] [NOTIFICATION:1] [] [] [ecid: 004xGPJYrnnFw00Fzzx0g00006Gb000000] [tid: fb3c8c60]  [85004] MDX Member Name Cache subsystem recovered entries: 0, size: 0 bytes.

[2014-03-20T10:23:52.000+00:00] [OracleBIServerComponent] [NOTIFICATION:1] [] [] [ecid: 004xGPJYrnnFw00Fzzx0g00006Gb000000] [tid: fb3c8c60]  [85008] MDX Member Name Cache subsystem statistics - Entries: 0, Sizes: 0 bytes, Overall Queries: 0, Hits: 0(0%), Misses: 0(0%).

[2014-03-20T10:23:52.000+00:00] [OracleBIServerComponent] [NOTIFICATION:1] [] [] [ecid: 004xGPJYrnnFw00Fzzx0g00006Gb000000] [tid: fb3c8c60]  [85007] MDX Member Name Cache subsystem stopped.

[2014-03-20T10:23:53.000+00:00] [OracleBIServerComponent] [NOTIFICATION:1] [] [] [ecid: 004xGPJYrnnFw00Fzzx0g00006Gb000000] [tid: fb3c8c60]  [14058] Unloaded all subject areas.

[2014-03-20T10:23:53.000+00:00] [OracleBIServerComponent] [ERROR:1] [] [] [ecid: ] [tid: fb3c8c60]  [nQSError: 46131] Unresolved host name: JustiziaInf. Could not get details about the specified host
```

The part of log important is:

**[nQSError: 46131] Unresolved host name: JustiziaInf. Could not get details about the specified host**

Any idea?

Comment: Check MDS and DEVBIPLATFORM users in the database whether they are locked or not. I faced an issue similar to this long time back.

Comment: The MDS and DEV_BIPLATFORM users are unlocked.